# EditorGUI Serialized PropertyField vs. other field types

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

This is essentially a 'what are the pros and cons' question.

Basically, in Unity Editor scripting, an `EditorGUI.PropertyField(...)` requires some sort of `SerializedProperty` taken from a `SerializedObject` version of your asset or data, whereas another field like `EditorGUI.TextField(...)` can be used without the serialization steps, so I'm wondering where/when you should use a PropertyField and when you should not.

I actually began with PropertyFields, but as my db manager grew I ran into more and more problems with editing and saving the data, until eventually I wound up right back at `EditorGUI.TextField`

Now I can't remember why I started using `SerializedProperty` in the first place and figure there's some advantage I'm missing (i.e. a way to update save data in a way that doesn't cause lag every time the user updates an item name and causes a call to `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets()`)

Thanks for your time.

Here is a section of my editor script:

```
    void OnGUI()
{
    if (db == null) db = new ItemDB();

    Item item;

    // ...

    GUILayout.Label("Items");
    scrollOffset = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollOffset);
    for(int i = 0, len = db.size; i < len; i++)
    {
        item   = db.items[i];

        /*
        Begin GUILayout formatting
        */
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(item.itemId.ToString(), GUILayout.Width(48f));
            item.itemName = EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.itemName);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Eq Slot", GUILayout.Width(48f));
            item.eqSlot = (Item.EqSlot)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(item.eqSlot);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Space(24f);
        /*
        End GUILayout formatting
        */
    }
    GUILayout.EndScrollView();
}

/*
 * Runs 10 frames a second to let the inspector refresh.
 * Saving 'dirty' assets is kinda heavy work, so mark them in OnGUI then save them here.
 */
void OnInspectorUpdate()
{
    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
}
```

And here's a sample of the Item class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
// ...

public int itemId;

[SerializeField]
private string _itemName;

[SerializeField]
private EqSlot _eqSlot = EqSlot.Null;

public string itemName
{
    get { return _itemName; }
    set
    {
        if (_itemName != value)
        {
            _itemName = value;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
    }
}

public EqSlot eqSlot
{
    get { return _eqSlot; }
    set
    {
        if (_eqSlot != value)
        {
            _eqSlot = value;
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm up-voting the question because I'm also curious of the answer... one thing I found in my (admittedly very limited) experience with custom editor scripts is that I couldn't manage to do an 'old school' style field for something like a Font property.  I had to throw it through the SerializedProperty magic to get it to render the Font selection box I was wanting.  (very likely I could have gotten it working with the other method though if I knew what I was doing)

Comment: I think I've remembered one reason why I launched into serialized properties right away.

TextField, LabelField, EnumPopup, etc can be used for primitive types, but I think 'EditorGUI.PropertyField` must be used if you want to display custom types/classes. Since my extension's architecture changed, that became unnecessary, so I could go back to a simple TextField.

Comment: I still think that there may be some advantages to memory/speed by using PropertyField, however? I still want to hear input from others with more experience.